# Directly signing an Office Word document using XML

Tags: c#, xml, ms-office, openxml

I'm trying to sign a Microsoft Office Word file using C# in direct XML format.

There are some questions and ambiguousness arises here like:

- How should I fill in the digest values, what value should I exactly digest for each reference, and what value should I digest for each transform?
- What value should I sign to create the `SignatureValue`?
- And what certificate should I include in x509 data and how? (We don't exactly have a certificate so a guide for creating one is appreciated.)

The last question is am I doing this correctly? Maybe there is something wrong here and I have missed a package that would otherwise itself interact with the openxml document and sign it.

But remember though that I am actually trying to sign a data with an external token which has a pkcs11 interface available(but no CSP) so I have used the PKCS11 Interop library to migrate it to c#, but I'm still a little confused here.

- Is there a package that I can use to sign word documents?
- Or is there a package that eases openXML interation?
- Or do I have to do it manually?

Just for heads up any library that does the openXML interaction should also allow me to sign the documents using the pkcs11 commands (i.e which gives me the bytestream to sign and digest but does the other parts itself, pkcs11 is really should not be considered an importance here(you can replace it with my custom algorithm))

BTW a signature builder in XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="idPackageSignature">
  <SignedInfo>
    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
    <Reference Type="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#Object" URI="#idPackageObject">
      <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
      <DigestValue/>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Type="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#Object" URI="#idOfficeObject">
      <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
      <DigestValue/>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" URI="#idSignedProperties">
      <Transforms>
        <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
      </Transforms>
      <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
      <DigestValue/>
    </Reference>
  </SignedInfo>
  <SignatureValue/>
  <KeyInfo>
    <X509Data>
      <X509Certificate/>
    </X509Data>
  </KeyInfo>
  <Object Id="idPackageObject">
    <Manifest>
      <Reference URI="/_rels/.rels?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/RelationshipTransform">
            <mdssi:RelationshipReference xmlns:mdssi="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/digital-signature" SourceId="rId1"/>
          </Transform>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
        <DigestValue/>
      </Reference>
      <Reference URI="/word/_rels/document.xml.rels?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/RelationshipTransform">
            <mdssi:RelationshipReference xmlns:mdssi="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/digital-signature" SourceId="rId5"/>
            <mdssi:RelationshipReference xmlns:mdssi="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/digital-signature" SourceId="rId4"/>
            <mdssi:RelationshipReference xmlns:mdssi="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/digital-signature" SourceId="rId3"/>
            <mdssi:RelationshipReference xmlns:mdssi="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/digital-signature" SourceId="rId2"/>
            <mdssi:RelationshipReference xmlns:mdssi="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/digital-signature" SourceId="rId1"/>
          </Transform>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
        <DigestValue/>
      </Reference>
      <Reference URI="/word/document.xml?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml">
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
        <DigestValue/>
      </Reference>
      <Reference URI="/word/fontTable.xml?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.fontTable+xml">
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
        <DigestValue/>
      </Reference>
      <Reference URI="/word/settings.xml?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.settings+xml">
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
        <DigestValue/>
      </Reference>
      <Reference URI="/word/styles.xml?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.styles+xml">
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
        <DigestValue/>
      </Reference>
      <Reference URI="/word/theme/theme1.xml?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml">
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
        <DigestValue/>
      </Reference>
      <Reference URI="/word/webSettings.xml?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.webSettings+xml">
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
        <DigestValue/>
      </Reference>
    </Manifest>
    <SignatureProperties>
      <SignatureProperty Id="idSignatureTime" Target="#idPackageSignature">
        <mdssi:SignatureTime xmlns:mdssi="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/digital-signature">
          <mdssi:Format>YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD</mdssi:Format>
          <mdssi:Value>2015-11-22T17:21:28Z</mdssi:Value>
        </mdssi:SignatureTime>
      </SignatureProperty>
    </SignatureProperties>
  </Object>
  <Object Id="idOfficeObject">
    <SignatureProperties>
      <SignatureProperty Id="idOfficeV1Details" Target="#idPackageSignature">
        <SignatureInfoV1 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/digsig">
          <SetupID/>
          <SignatureText/>
          <SignatureImage/>
          <SignatureComments>TEST SIGNING</SignatureComments>
          <WindowsVersion>10.0</WindowsVersion>
          <OfficeVersion>15.0</OfficeVersion>
          <ApplicationVersion>15.0</ApplicationVersion>
          <Monitors>1</Monitors>
          <HorizontalResolution>1920</HorizontalResolution>
          <VerticalResolution>1080</VerticalResolution>
          <ColorDepth>32</ColorDepth>
          <SignatureProviderId>{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</SignatureProviderId>
          <SignatureProviderUrl/>
          <SignatureProviderDetails>9</SignatureProviderDetails>
          <SignatureType>1</SignatureType>
        </SignatureInfoV1>
      </SignatureProperty>
    </SignatureProperties>
  </Object>
  <Object>
    <xd:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xd="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Target="#idPackageSignature">
      <xd:SignedProperties Id="idSignedProperties">
        <xd:SignedSignatureProperties>
          <xd:SigningTime>2015-11-22T17:21:28Z</xd:SigningTime>
          <xd:SigningCertificate>
            <xd:Cert>
              <xd:CertDigest>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
                <DigestValue/>
              </xd:CertDigest>
              <xd:IssuerSerial>
                <X509IssuerName>E=ali@ali.com, CN=ALI-PC, OU=ALI-PC, O=ALI-PC, L=ALI-PC, S=ALI-PC, C=98</X509IssuerName>
                <X509SerialNumber>1</X509SerialNumber>
              </xd:IssuerSerial>
            </xd:Cert>
          </xd:SigningCertificate>
          <xd:SignaturePolicyIdentifier>
            <xd:SignaturePolicyImplied/>
          </xd:SignaturePolicyIdentifier>
        </xd:SignedSignatureProperties>
        <xd:SignedDataObjectProperties>
          <xd:CommitmentTypeIndication>
            <xd:CommitmentTypeId>
              <xd:Identifier>http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.2.2#ProofOfOrigin</xd:Identifier>
              <xd:Description>Created and approved this document</xd:Description>
            </xd:CommitmentTypeId>
            <xd:AllSignedDataObjects/>
            <xd:CommitmentTypeQualifiers>
              <xd:CommitmentTypeQualifier>TEST SIGNING</xd:CommitmentTypeQualifier>
            </xd:CommitmentTypeQualifiers>
          </xd:CommitmentTypeIndication>
        </xd:SignedDataObjectProperties>
      </xd:SignedProperties>
    </xd:QualifyingProperties>
  </Object>
</Signature>
```

Comment: BTW thanks for the edit mod :)

Comment: Note: I have reformatted the xml code which was lacking several `<` characters. I don't know whether or not that has been an artifact of the SO editor.

Comment: Well lets say in short I need to implement a project like: http://www.signfiles.com/signature-library/

Comment: So does anyone know an open source alternative of the aforementioned library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the source code of [this project](http://assinadordigital.codeplex.com/), it covers basic digital signatures for MS Office documents.
Note that the code is a bit outdated but the principles are the same

Comment: good example, however its using the packagedigitalsignaturemanager class in windowsbase library, which means no source code, and therefore I would be unable to customize it. now if u also provide me with the source code of the above class or an alternative I guess it will be the right answer.

Comment: Another interesting project towards digital signatures (XAdES) in office documents is [here](https://github.com/Caliper/Xades) (in French, but source code is in c# :) )

Comment: Excellent, even though the project is designed for detached signature, I can still use it for reference up my original program and create a minimal signature for it(cause it looks like that Xades actually points to canonical object instead of indirect referencing which makes things easier) I will upvote the answer now but when I'm finished I will mark this as an answer (that is, if its correct).

Comment: Mostly fixed my problem but another problem just exists, Ill mark this as the answer anyway.