# Directly signing an Office Word docx using OPC(Open Packaging Conventions)

Tags: c#, xml, openxml, digital-signature

Coming from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33872028/directly-signing-an-office-word-document-using-xml),

I was able to finally produce a correct detached signature.

However:

- when I'm trying to produce an enveloping signature, it says that the generated digest value from object is incorrect
- when I'm trying to sign a relationship object, it says that the relationship file is not valid(ly processed).

So we have 2 questions here:

- What value should I exactly digest for an enveloping signature(Or what value to digest from an object if we are referencing an object in our signedinfo data) ?
- How to process a correct relationship transform and what value should I digest of it?

BTW, a detached signature looks like this(which I'm able to correctly sign):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="idPackageSignature">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/>
      <Reference URI="/word/document.xml?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml">
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
          <DigestValue>
          </DigestValue>
      </Reference>
      <Reference URI="/word/webSettings.xml?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.webSettings+xml">
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
          <DigestValue>
          </DigestValue>
      </Reference>
      <Reference URI="/word/settings.xml?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.settings+xml">
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
          <DigestValue>
          </DigestValue>
      </Reference>
      <Reference URI="/word/styles.xml?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.styles+xml">
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
          <DigestValue>
          </DigestValue>
      </Reference>
      <Reference URI="/word/theme/theme1.xml?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml">
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
          <DigestValue>
          </DigestValue>
      </Reference>
      <Reference URI="/word/fontTable.xml?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.fontTable+xml">
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
          <DigestValue>
          </DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>
    </SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
      <X509Data>
        <X509Certificate>
        </X509Certificate>
      </X509Data>
    </KeyInfo>
  </Signature>
```

But an enveloping signature looks like this(which I can't reproduce correct digest value of object):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Signature Id="SignatureIdValue" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
  <SignedInfo>
    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
    <Reference URI="#idPackageObject" Type="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#Object">
      <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
      <DigestValue>
      </DigestValue>
    </Reference>
  </SignedInfo>
  <SignatureValue>
  </SignatureValue>
  <KeyInfo>
    <X509Data>
      <X509Certificate>
        </X509Certificate>
    </X509Data>
  </KeyInfo>
  <Object Id="idPackageObject">
    <Manifest>
      <Reference URI="/word/document.xml?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml">
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <DigestValue>
        </DigestValue>
      </Reference>
      <Reference URI="/word/webSettings.xml?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.webSettings+xml">
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <DigestValue>
        </DigestValue>
      </Reference>
      <Reference URI="/word/settings.xml?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.settings+xml">
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <DigestValue>
        </DigestValue>
      </Reference>
      <Reference URI="/word/styles.xml?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.styles+xml">
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <DigestValue>
        </DigestValue>
      </Reference>
      <Reference URI="/word/theme/theme1.xml?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.theme+xml">
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <DigestValue>
        </DigestValue>
      </Reference>
      <Reference URI="/word/fontTable.xml?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.fontTable+xml">
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <DigestValue>
        </DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </Signature>
```

Tried digesting the content inside of the object node without luck.

Remember though that although I can produce a valid detached signature, it's considered logically invalid as stated in the ECMA standard.

finally, a relationship reference looks like this(which I also should be able to digest and sign):

```xml
<Reference URI="/word/_rels/document.xml.rels?ContentType=application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml">
  <Transforms>
    <Transform Algorithm="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/RelationshipTransform">
      <xdssi:RelationshipReference xmlns:xdssi="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/digital-signature" SourceId="rId3"/>
      <xdssi:RelationshipReference xmlns:xdssi="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/digital-signature" SourceId="rId2"/>
      <xdssi:RelationshipReference xmlns:xdssi="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/digital-signature" SourceId="rId1"/>
      <xdssi:RelationshipReference xmlns:xdssi="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/digital-signature" SourceId="rId5"/>
      <xdssi:RelationshipReference xmlns:xdssi="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/digital-signature" SourceId="rId4"/>
    </Transform>
    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
  </Transforms>
  <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
  <DigestValue>
  </DigestValue>
</Reference>
```

Comment: I do not think this is related to the "OPC" tag as defined on SO. Please remove the "OPC" tag from this question in order to maintain SO well organized.

Comment: Thanks, I thought it was "Open Packaging Conventions", you know its the first result that pops up in google when searching for this word :)